# div not floating all the way to the top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a page using bootstrap3 with 6 panels, 3 col-md-4 and 3 col-md-8.
The 3 col-md-4 should float left and the 3 col-md-8 should float right,
but each one of them have a condition to exist (so there are not always 6 panels on the page).

When all 6 of them are apearing the layout is like this:

```
[col-md-4(1)][  col-md-8(1)  ]
[col-md-4(2)][  col-md-8(2)  ]
[col-md-4(3)][  col-md-8(3)  ]
```

And if col-md-4(1) is missing for example the layout looks like this:

```
[col-md-4(2)][  col-md-8(1)  ]
[col-md-4(3)][  col-md-8(2)  ]
             [  col-md-8(3)  ]
```

But every panel only goes up 1 "level" at max so if col-md-4(1) and (2) are missing for example the layout will look like this:

```
             [  col-md-8(1)  ]
[col-md-4(3)][  col-md-8(2)  ]
             [  col-md-8(3)  ]
```

So what is the right way to stack this panels so they work properly?

I saw an answer in another post that gave this "fix":

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="first"></div>
        <div id="second"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="third"></div>
        <div id="fourth"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#left {
    float: left;
}
#right {
    float: right;
}
```

But when i tried using that the result was:

```
[col-md-4(1)]
[col-md-4(2)]
[col-md-4(3)]
[  col-md-8(1)  ]
[  col-md-8(2)  ]
[  col-md-8(3)  ]
```

The col-md-8 ones did not float right

Comment: Not look a bootstrap official? and check http://getbootstrap.com/css/ is a learning easier

Answer (score 1):

Nope you shouldn't do it like this, what i get is you want all your col with value 4 is on left and all columns with value 8 on the right ?
 
You may check this link i have just made:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    This is col-md 4
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    This is col-md-8
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    This is col-md 4
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    This is col-md-8
  </div>
</div><div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    This is col-md 4
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    This is col-md-8
  </div>
</div><div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    This is col-md 4
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    This is col-md-8
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-md-4
{

  background-color: lightblue;
}
.col-md-8
{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Here is the link
http://codepen.io/Rehman/pen/WxaGbE

Comment: The problem is, like i said, that a panel may or may not exist, for example there is a panel that is only created if a variable $xyz is not null, if you go to your code and delete one of the col-md-4 for example the col-md-8 next to it will go to the left, I dont want that, I want it to stay on the right

Comment: @TomásRezende check the code again i have updated it, if you know that this col-md-8's col-md-4 is missing you can invoke a class of *right* and it will drag the column to left. Your floats are not working because bootstrap has already floated them left and right by default, so you need to do *important* thingy to override that property. (that is discouraged but it may help you for now)